# I'd like to change or to hide [CEG] when use Twilio sending message

Tags: sms, twilio

When I send the message by Twilio to someone, there is the "[CEG]" in the sending message.
I don't know how to change the message [CEG] or hide the message.
Please, help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, Twilio developer evangelist here. I'm not sure what you mean exactly here. Could you share your code and the outcome that you're seeing, please?

Comment: I've sent

var client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken); 

client.messages.create({ 
    to: "+XXXXXXXXXXXXX", 
    from: "+XXXXXXXXXX", 
    body: "test",   
}, function(err, message) { 
    console.log(message.sid); 
});

But
I receive like that below.
test[ceg]

Comment: Have you upgraded your account? Or are you still using the free version?

Comment: Can you drop me an email at philnash at twilio dot com so I can take a look into this further, please?

Comment: Oh~ Sorry. Because this is not personal account, this is our company's one. So I could not give you it. sorry.

Comment: I got this too,and then,Do you fix it ?

Answer (score 3):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

This is intentional behaviour in China. Chinese phone carriers require an ID to be appended to the end of a message before delivery. Twilio's ID is CEG so we append it to all messages in China, it is not possible to remove it.